# Show a div when hovering on an element and keeps it displayed when hovering on this new div

Tags: html, css

I'll try to explain myself :
I have a Top navigation like this : Test1 Test2 Test3
When I hover on one of the element of my top nav i want to show a sub nav underneath with other navigation nodes.
For now I achieved to show the subnav when hovering on the top nav but when my cursor is not hovering the top nav anymore the subnav disappear and so the subnav navigation nodes are not clickable ...

I do not have any idea on how to make this if someone could help me I gladly appreciate

Hope I was clear enough

Html :

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IDropdownItemProps> {
    const item = this.props.item;
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            onClick={item.Url ? () => this.onLinkClicked(item.Url as string) : void 0}
            ref={this.linkRef}
            target="_blank"
            data-interception="off"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className={styles.node}
          >
            {item.Title as string}
          </a>
          {(item.Children as INavigationNode[]).length ? (
            <div className={styles.subNav}>
              {(item.Children as INavigationNode[]).map((node) => (
                <div className={styles.level2Container}>
                  <a
                    className={styles.subNode}
                    target="_blank"
                    data-interception="off"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    {node.Title as string}
                  </a>
                  {(node.Children as INavigationNode[]).map((subNode) => (
                    <div className={styles.level3Container} style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>
                      <a
                        target="_blank"
                        data-interception="off"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        className={styles.subNode}
                      >
                        {subNode.Title as string}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

and my css :

```
.navbar {
  font-family: "Comfortaa", cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent;

  .node {
    color: #12548e;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar > ul > li > div {
  display: none;
}

.navbar > ul > li:hover {
  .node {
    color: #72bc92;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .subNode {
    padding: 5px 0;
  }

  .subNav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: fixed;
    left: 48px;
    top: 219px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20%;
    border-top: 2px solid #72bc92;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.582);

    .level2Container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 20px 0;
      width: 300px;

      .subNode {
        color: #12548e;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    .level3Container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      .subNode {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: rgb(122, 122, 122);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

generated HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a target="_bank" data-interception="off" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="node_b73ab580">Groupe</a>
        <div class="subNav_b73ab580">
            <div class="level2Container_b73ab580">
                <a class="subNode_B73ab580" target="_blank" data-interception="off"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer">Présentation groupe</a>
                <div class="level3Container_b73ab580" style="font-size: 12px;">
                    <a target="_blank" data-interception="off" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        class="subNode_B73ab580">TEST</a>
                </div>
                <div class="level3Container_b73ab580" style="font-size: 12px;"></div>
                <div class="level3Container_b73ab580" style="font-size: 12px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="level2Container_b73ab580"></div>
            <div class="level2Container_b73ab580"></div>
            <div class="level2Container_b73ab580"></div>
            <div class="level2Container_b73ab580"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Attach full HTML and CSS code.

Comment: It's done @Lukas I am using react

Comment: That is not easily debugable for anyone here, who doesn't have your react setup available. It would really be preferable, if you showed the rendered HTML this produces.

Comment: I editted with the rendered HTML

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like `react-portal-tooltip` would make this easier.